# Is it possible to have users pick a shipping date?

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping, ce-1.8.1.0

We have a cheese store and only like to ship packages on Mondays to make sure they don't sit anywhere over the weekend.  We're pretty small and don't always have some one working on Mail orders so we get the occasional complaint when people don't check the terms of service.  When the customer is placing an order we would like to force them to pick a shipping date at which point they'll see that only Monday's are available and then have a message telling them that if they want it shipped on a different day to please call the store.

I haven't been able to figure out how to do this, or any extensions that allow it.  If any one knows of any that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

An **easy solution** would be to create an option for every product in `Manage Products > [Product Name] > Custom Options`. But this solution has 2 inconvenients: 1) you will have to implement it for at product level, which can be quite tedious if your store has many products; 2) I don't think this option lets you prevent customers from picking another day than a Monday, so you would have to add a message in the label option — somtehing like "please only select Mondays".

If you want **a more complete solution** that enables you to effectively manage your delivery schedule, you should check [Mage World Advance Delivery Schedule](http://www.mage-world.com/magento-delivery-date-schedule-extension.html).

Comment: Thanks,  the Mage extension looks like it may work.  We have enough products that I don't want to have it as an option for every product, but I'm going to get in contact with Mage and see if their's will work.

Comment: Perfect. Hope it suits your needs (which i can practially guarantee as I have used it myself). If this turns out to solve your problem, don't forget to mark my answer as accepted ;)

Comment: I haven't forgotten this, just haven't gotten around to implementing it yet.